# pass data from view1 to view2 using local storage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, local-storage

I am new to angular and I want to pass data from one page to another page using local storage.I have tried a lot but unable to find the correct answer

Comment: You should explain here what you tried.

Comment: You need to update what have you tried where folks can suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use factory like below.

```
angular
    .module('xx.services', [])
    .factory('xxStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            set: function(_key, _value) {
                $window.localStorage[_key] = _value;
            },
            get: function(_key) {
                return $window.localStorage[_key];
            }
        };
    }])
```

You can use set function to save data in the first page, and then reuse using get function in the other page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use library which already wrapped localStorage functionality in angular area. So there are few such popular solutions like: ngStorage and angular-local-storage. I prefer first one.

[Git page](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage), here you can find all information about installing, and using.

Just for example here is sample

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage'])
    .config(['$localStorageProvider',
    function ($localStorageProvider) {
        $localStorageProvider.get('MyKey');

        $localStorageProvider.set('MyKey', { k: 'value' });
    }]);
```